# How to disable a UBSAN rule on std lib?

Tags: c++, clang, ubsan

I experience this error with UBSAN:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/hash.h:107:40: runtime error: left shift of 7308895138221481827 by 48 places cannot be represented in type 'unsigned long'
```

So, I'd like to exclude the shift rule for this specific (as I don't have control over it).

So, as the documentation mention, I tried to pass a suppression file as `UBSAN_OPTIONS`:

```
shift-base:hash.h
shift-exponent:hash.h
```

It did not exclude the error, my first attempt was:

```
shift:hash.h
```

Then the compiler spits an error:

```
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: failed to parse suppressions
```

I probably should have noticed something. It's probably the path, tho.

---

Full log:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/hash.h:107:40: runtime error: left shift of 7308895138221481827 by 48 places cannot be represented in type 'unsigned long'
    #0 0x104d94f5c in std::__1::__murmur2_or_cityhash<unsigned long, 64ul>::__rotate_by_at_least_1(unsigned long, int) hash.h:107
    #1 0x104d93094 in std::__1::__murmur2_or_cityhash<unsigned long, 64ul>::__hash_len_0_to_16(char const*, unsigned long) hash.h:132
    #2 0x104d91cf0 in std::__1::__murmur2_or_cityhash<unsigned long, 64ul>::operator()(void const*, unsigned long) hash.h:226
    #3 0x104d91c50 in unsigned long std::__1::__do_string_hash[abi:v15006]<char const*>(char const*, char const*) char_traits.h:920
    #4 0x104d903f0 in std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>::operator()(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) const string:4565
    #5 0x104d9ac9c in std::__1::__hash_const_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, void*>*> std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>>::find<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) const __hash_table:2333
    #6 0x104d9aac8 in unsigned long std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>>::__count_unique<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) const __hash_table:2515
    #7 0x104d9a93c in std::__1::unordered_set<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>>::count[abi:v15006](std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) const unordered_set:798
    #8 0x104d1973c in testing::internal::(anonymous namespace)::UnitTestFilter::MatchesName(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) const gtest.cc:781
    #9 0x104d6cac4 in testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::GetTestSuite(char const*, char const*, void (*)(), void (*)()) gtest.cc:5766
    #10 0x104d37dc0 in testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::AddTestInfo(void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::TestInfo*) gtest-internal-inl.h:690
    #11 0x104d37810 in testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*) gtest.cc:2771
    #12 0x104cd8e90 in __cxx_global_var_init engine_binding_test.cc:32
    #13 0x104cd9dc8 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_engine_binding_test.cc engine_binding_test.cc
    #14 0x18157c1d4  (<unknown module>)
    #15 0x1815bde90  (<unknown module>)
    #16 0x1815b11a0  (<unknown module>)
    #17 0x18155c2d4  (<unknown module>)
    #18 0x1815b01c8  (<unknown module>)
    #19 0x1815bd954  (<unknown module>)
    #20 0x181578858  (<unknown module>)
    #21 0x181578c0c  (<unknown module>)
    #22 0x18157c260  (<unknown module>)
    #23 0x181578d8c  (<unknown module>)
    #24 0x18159c980  (<unknown module>)
    #25 0x1815612cc  (<unknown module>)
    #26 0x18155fe14  (<unknown module>)

SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/hash.h:107:40 in
```

Comment: Did you try the absolute path?

Comment: In [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#available-checks) I've found `unsigned-shift-base`. So write [suppression file](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#runtime-suppressions) with this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answer @HolyBlackCat and @Marek R

I did not manage to make it work.

But I realized that it came from gtest dependency, so I finally added the compile options `-fno-sanitize=unsigned-shift-base` for `gtest` target :)